# auth.views.Loginview shows "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request' "

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am trying to use djangos built-in `LoginView`, but it showed an error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
```

**batchbook/user/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from .forms import LoginForm

app_name = 'user'
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'login',
        LoginView.as_view(
            authentication_form=LoginForm,
            success_url='/',
            template_name='user/login.html'),
        name='login'),
    path(
        'logout',
        LogoutView.as_view(template_name='user/logout.html'),
        name='logout'),
]
```

**batchbook/batchbook/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('user/', include(auth_urls)),
    re_path(
        '^$',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='site/index.html'),
        name='index'),
]
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .validators import usn_validator

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    usn = forms.CharField(
        max_length=11,
        validators = (usn_validator,),
        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control'
        })
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control'
        })
    )
```

**validators.py**

```
usn_validator = RegexValidator(
    regex='^1BM[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{3}$',
    message='Please enter correct USN',
    code='usn_err'
)
```

Here is the error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'user']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in dispatch
  66.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  133.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in get_context_data
  99.         context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_context_data
  66.             kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()

File "C:\Users\bhask\Miniconda3\envs\batchbook\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_form
  33.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

Exception Type: TypeError at /user/login
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
```

Comment: This code does not give that error. Please show the whole traceback.

Comment: "Switch to copy-and-paste view"  gave the above traceback. How do i get the whole traceback.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the link. Really you should post that in the question. But the traceback is pointing to the LoginForm as the problem - is that your own form? You should post the code.

Comment: Yes it's my own form. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

Aparently, the `LoginView` uses djangos [`AuthenticationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) as its default. The docs for that form say:

> Takes `request` as its first positional argument, ...

That means that `LoginView` will pass `request` as an argument to your form. Djangos default `forms.Form` does not expect that (look at the source [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/forms/forms/#BaseForm)).

So you can try to override your `__init__()` method to allow that extra argument:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    usn = forms.CharField...
    password = forms.CharField...

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # simply do not pass 'request' to the parent
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Let us know how that goes.