# Apply Autocomplete=off to Django password reset confirm form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am using Django 2.2 with Python 3.7

Following a security audit, I have been asked to ensure all security-related fields on forms in our application render with the autocomplete="off" attribute. Whether or not this is a valid and useful security measure is out of scope... unfortunately. So far, I have accomplished this by extending the form in question. For example, with the PasswordResetForm (where the user enters the email associated with the account):

```py
class NoAutocompletePasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PasswordResetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete': 'off'})
```

And then instructing the relevant auth view to use it like so (in urls.py):

```py
    url(r'^accounts/password_reset/?$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(form_class=forms.NoAutocompletePasswordResetForm)),
```

This worked fine up until the Password Reset Confirm View, which uses the SetPasswordForm. The first attempt there went something like this:

```py
url(r'^accounts/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z\-]+)/$', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(form_class=forms.NoAutocompleteSetPasswordForm)),

class NoAutocompleteSetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['new_password1'].widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete': 'off'})
        self.fields['new_password2'].widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete': 'off'})
```

However this just yields a TypeError, on the super() line, with the detail that `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'`, despite the presence of a named `user` argument to the init of that form, as seen [in the Django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py). But for funsies, I tried passing the user as a positional arg instead, like so:

```py
class NoAutocompleteSetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        myKwargs = kwargs.copy()
        myUser = myKwargs['user']
        del myKwargs['user']

        myArgs = (*args, myUser)

        super(SetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*myArgs, **myKwargs)
        self.fields['new_password1'].widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete': 'off'})
        self.fields['new_password2'].widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete': 'off'})
```

With this tweak, the form makes it through construction, but Django errs during template rendering instead. In particular, I get the following stack trace:

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/reset/MjA/set-password/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError
TypeError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 987, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 671, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 796, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 74, in errors
    return self.form.errors.get(self.name, self.form.error_class())
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 381, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 393, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Delorean\delorean_env_37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 258, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'get'
```

So, how do I get this form to render with autocomplete='off'?

Comment: `myKwargs = dict(**kwargs)` <- Don't do this. `kwargs` is already a dictionary.

Comment: I was doing that more to get a copy than to cast, but good point. I've changed it to kwargs.copy(). No change in result though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hair pulling, I got it working. Drawing inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349150/auth-views-loginview-shows-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-reque), and based off the fact that I was at one point getting an error about an unexpected user argument, I changed my form to the below:

```py
class NoAutocompleteSetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user

        super(SetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['new_password1'].widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete': 'off'})
        self.fields['new_password2'].widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete': 'off'})
```

It now renders the page with the autocomplete attribute, as required.